# Functionality implementation: Processes or Threads division?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ipc, embedded-linux

I'm working on an application (C++ combined with Qt for graphic part) to be run on an embedded Linux platform. I need know how to divide the application in different "cores" each one taking care of a different part of the application in such a way to improve stability, efficiency and security of the application itself.

My doubt is: is it more convenient to divide functionalities into threads or to fork different processes?

Let me provide a functional view of the application: there are different user interfaces each one allowing users to do more or less the same things (don't mind about data consistency, I've already solved this problem). Each of these interfaces must act as a stand-alone (like different terminal of the same system). I want all of them to send and receive messages from the same "core" which will take care of updating application data or do other proper stuff.

What's the best way to implement the division between the inner "core" and a user interface?

For sure I'm missing some knowledge but so far I came up with two alternatives:
1 - fork a child from father "core" and let the child execute a specific UI program (I have no practical experience of doing this so how, in this case, can I make father and child communicate (baring in mind that child is a new process)?)
2 - create different threads for each core and UI.

I need this division because the application is required to be as stable as possible and capable of restarting a UI in the case of a crash. Keep in mind also that the overall application wont have infinite memory and resources available.

Thanks in advance for your help, regards.

Comment: Process communication can be done using files, DB, or a network connection. IMHO all three method reduce stability, efficiency and security. Use threads.

Comment: In Qt the UI can run on only one thread in a given process.

Comment: yes, I'm new to Qt. But I'm trying to use Qt only at ui level, not for inner cores.

Comment: @ahenderson - *Process communication can be done using files, DB, or a network connection.* There are a number of other options for interprocess communications on the same machine. Pipes, named pipes (fifos), semaphores, sockets, socketpairs, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a several reasons why going down the separate process route might is a good choice in an embedded system:

- Decoupling of component: running components as seperate processes is the ultimate decoupling.  Often useful when projects become very large
- Security and privilege management: Quite likely in an embedded system that some components need elevated privilege in order to control devices, whereas others are potential security hazards (for instance network facing components) you want to run with as little as little privilege as possible.  Other likely scenarios are components that need real-time threading or  to be able to `mmap()` a lot of system memory.  Overallocation of either will lock your system up in a way it won't recover from.
- Reliably: You can potentially respawn parts of the system if they fail leaving the remainder running

Building such an arrangement is actually easier than others here are suggesting - Qt has really good support for [dbus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) - which nicely takes care of your IPC, and is used extensive in the Linux desktop for system management functionality.

As for the scenario you describe, you might want to daemonise the 'core' of the application and then allow client connections over dbus from UI components.

Comment: thanks! I'm slowly accepting this solution... also due to the respawning ability you mentioned which I would like to implement too.

Answer (score 0):

Running the UI in a different thread won't give you much in the way of additional stability -- the other thread can trash your heap of the engine, and even if you terminate the thread any resources it has won't be recycled.

You can improve stability a bit by having a really strong wall of abstraction between the Engine and the UI.  So this isn't completely futile.

Multiple processes require lots of hoops to jump through -- you need a method of IPC (interprocess communication).

Note that IPC and to a lesser extent walls of abstraction can add to the overhead of your program.

An important question to ask is "how much data has to pass between the UI and the Engine?" -- if it is little enough data (like "start the task" from UI to engine, and "this task is 50% done" from engine to UI), IPC is less of a hassle.  If you are an interactive painting application with real-time full-screen updates of an image, IPC is more annoying and less practical.

Now, a quick google on Qt and IPC tells me that there is a Qt extension for embedded linux that allows the Qt signals and slots to pass messages between processes: Qt COmmunications Protocol (QCOP).  One issue I have had with frameworks like this is that it can easily lead to entanglements between the client and server state that can compromise stability on the other end of the communications pipe, compared to relatively simple protocols.

Comment: thanks for reply! traffic between Ui and Engine (actually the very same name I used on my own while developing) is dramatically little: chars representing an internal protocol format.